# Descarga los mismos archivos xml en zip

Tags: php, sql, zip, headers

actualmente estoy descargando xml de manera masiva en un zip, pero siempre me descarga los mismos 265 archivos, para descargarlos estoy empleando un procedimiento almacenado en el cual listo la ruta de los archivos xml, y los filtro por rango de fechas, pasa que al momento de descargarlo me descarga siempre los mismos 265, sin importar de que filtro le ponga, descarga siempre los mismos, ya he revisado listando el procedimiento y los filtros se aplican bien.

```
<?php
include '../../controlador/connec.inc.php';
$fecIni     = $_GET['fecIni'];
$fecFin     = $_GET['fecFin'];

$zipnme = "archivs.zip";
$sqlquery = $conn->prepare("SPU_PROVICIONES_CONXML ?,?");
$sqlquery->execute(['2021-01-01', '2021-08-31']);
$zipp = new ZipArchive;
if($zipp->open($zipnme, ZipArchive::CREATE)){
    while($file = $sqlquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $rute = $file['RUTA_ARCHIVO'];
            $zipp->addFile($rute);
    }
    $zipp->close();
    ob_clean ();
    header("Content-type:application/zip");
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$zipnme");
    header("Content-length:".filesize($zipnme));
    readfile("$zipnme");
}else{
    echo 'Fallo';
}
```

Este es el código que uso para descargar, estuve probando mandandole las fechas yo mismo y nada, al momento de listar $rute, me lista todo lo que se debería descargar, pero en el zip no estan esos archivos.

El código del procedimiento almacenado que uso es el siguiente:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPU_PROVICIONES_CONXML]
@fecIni date,
@fecFin date
AS BEGIN
SELECT RUTA_ARCHIVO, FECHA
FROM view_proviciones_xml 
WHERE FECHA BETWEEN @fecIni AND @fecFin
END
GO
```

[image: La primera es la cantidad de registros que me bota el query en el rango de fechas]

[image: Y la segunda es la que me descarga en el zip, y son siempre los mismos archivos]

Comment: Con crear varias versiones de la misma pregunta, créeme que no haces más fácil obtener respuesta. Todo lo contrario. PD. Si te editamos la mayúßcula sostenida en el título de la otra pregunta es para que no lo sigas usando ;)

Comment: Son problemas completamente distintos estimado, tenía un problema de descarga del archivo corrupto, y ya fue solucionado. Este problema es que no me descarga el rango de archivos que debería.

Comment: _I stand corrected_. NO es que no te creamos, pero no hay evidencia de que el procedimiento esté entregando lo que esperas :P Es necesario ver qué llega con diferentes intervalos

Comment: Si claro, adjunté la imagen, probé también con un rango mas corto, por mes, y me salen los mismos 265,  y deberían de ser menos los registros.

Comment: La cosa es que tu código PHP trabaja con lo que le entrega el procedimiento. Habría que ver el procedimiento para ver por qué entrega siempre lo mismo.

Comment: También lo he probado desde el mismo sql, y el rango que me da es tal cual como lo lista en la primera imágen.

Comment: Después de cerrar el zip ¿qué te devuelve `$zipp-> getStatusString()`?

Comment: Pon el código de tu procedimiento. Las imágenes no ayudan mucho

Comment: Ya añadí el código del procedimiento, aunque probando con el me funciona sin problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

logré solucionar mi problema, resulta que lo que hace zipArchive es descargar una copia de la ruta que le envías en tu servidor, de esa manera lo descarga tu navegador, yo para las pruebas previas que estuve realizando, estaba consultando solo del mes de agosto que tenía un registro de 265 archivos, por eso que la descarga era la misma, solucioné agregando la función unlink(), para que lo borre del servidor al momento que el usuario lo descarga, la actualización del código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
include '../../controlador/connec.inc.php';
$fecIni     = $_GET['fecIni'];
$fecFin     = $_GET['fecFin'];

$zipnme = "archivs.zip";
$sqlquery = $conn->prepare("SPU_PROVICIONES_CONXML ?,?");
$sqlquery->execute([$fecIni , $fecFin]);
$zipp = new ZipArchive();
$i = 0;
if($zipp->open($zipnme, ZipArchive::CREATE)){
    while($file = $sqlquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){                            
        $rute = $file['RUTA_ARCHIVO'];
        $zipp->addFile($rute);
        
    }        
    $zipp->close();
    ob_end_clean ();
    header("Content-type: application/zip text/xml"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$zipnme");
    header("Content-length: " . filesize($zipnme));
    readfile("$zipnme");
    flush(); //Vacia el buffer de salida del sistema.
    unlink($zipnme); //Elimina el archivo luego de que el usuario lo descarga.
}else{
    echo 'Fallo';
}
```

Y de esa manera solucioné mi problema.